# My breakpoints don't hit when I run it for the first time?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013. I use a single start up project. There are more than 8 projects in the solution. Here is what I used to do when I was on Visual Studio 2010;

I would Build the solution. Then run it from its .exe file in /bin/Debug, then on Visual Studio, I would Attach to Process and it would start debugging and it would always hit the breakpoints as long as the source code and the .exe are not different.

This is the same thing that I do on Visual Studio 2013. I put the breakpoints in a file in my startup project. I build the solution (it says it successfully builded on the output window), or I Start Without Debugging, then attach to process, it says "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. The source code is different from the original version" Then I stop debugging, and without building again, I run the .exe again, attach it, then the breakpoints start hitting. Why do I have to close my .exe and then start it again? I use attach to process a lot and this 'must do twice to hit' is really annoying. I haven't change any configuration or anything. What am I doing wrong? I swear I don't change the source code. Not even a single space. It says "Build succeeded" when I attach it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue. (on a webproject)

my temp solution:

1. **right** click the **web project**
2. Select **Property Pages**
3. Under **Build** --> Change the **Target Framework** to something else than the one selected (Apply the new framework)
4. Then Change back to your desired framework and **Debug**